# Ios error: Thread 1 under @auto release pool "EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access, back

The app crashes and shows this error when I hit the Back button. I have 2 view controllers. On the first vc the Start button works fine to switch to second view, but when I hit the Back button the app crashes and I get the error above on the line below @autorelease pool. I will also post the code for my start & back buttons. thx :)
    #import 
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate      class]));
}
}
```

First vc.H file Start Button (this works switching to second view)

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController  
{
IBOutlet UIButton *StartQuiz;
IBOutlet UIButton *HowToPlay;
IBOutlet UIButton *Credits;
IBOutlet UIButton *Back;
IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
}

-(IBAction)StartQuiz:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)HowToPlay:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Credits:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender;
```

`Firstvc.M` file

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)StartQuiz:(id)sender {
Questions *MenuToQuestions = [[Questions alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"Questions"
                              bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:MenuToQuestions.view];

}
```

`SecondVC.h` file (Back button crashes app)

```
 @interface Questions : UIViewController

{

IBOutlet UIButton *BasicOptics;
IBOutlet UIButton *EyeAnatomy;
IBOutlet UIButton *OphthalmicInstruments;
IBOutlet UIButton *Lenses;
IBOutlet UIButton *Transposition;
IBOutlet UIButton *Standards;
IBOutlet UIButton *Frames;
IBOutlet UIButton *Random; 
IBOutlet UIButton *Back;
IBOutlet UILabel *Cat1;
IBOutlet UILabel *Cat2;
IBOutlet UIButton *Right1;
IBOutlet UIButton *Right2;
IBOutlet UIButton *Right3;
IBOutlet UIButton *Right4;
IBOutlet UIButton *Wrong1;
IBOutlet UIButton *Wrong2;
IBOutlet UIButton *Wrong3;
IBOutlet UIButton *Wrong4;
IBOutlet UILabel *Answer1;
IBOutlet UILabel *Answer2;
IBOutlet UILabel *Answer3;
IBOutlet UILabel *Answer4;
IBOutlet UILabel *Question;
IBOutlet UILabel *SelectCategory;
IBOutlet UILabel *Lives;
IBOutlet UILabel *Score;
IBOutlet UILabel *LivesWord;
IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreWord;
IBOutlet UILabel *GameOver;
IBOutlet UILabel *FinalScore;
}

-(IBAction)BasicOptics:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)EyeAnatomy:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)OphthalmicInstruments:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Lenses:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Transposition:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Standards:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Frames:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Random:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Right:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Wrong:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender;

@end
```

`Secondvc.m` file

```
-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender {

ViewController *MenuToViewController = [[ViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"ViewController"
                              bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:MenuToViewController.view];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not holding a reference for your `MenuToViewController` instance anywhere. The view of the `MenuToViewController` gets added to the view hierarchy, so it gets retained, but as soon as the view tries to send a message to one of the outlets, your app crashes, because the controller has been released.

Once you create that controller, you could set it as instance variable (add `Questions *MenuToQuestions` to your `@interface`).

Comment: Thx for your response. I am a newby so if you could break it down for me. Should the @interface line in Questions.M look like this?? `@interface Questions *MenuToQuestions: UIViewController`

Comment: @MrsOptic No you don't create an `interface` like that.