# Back button crashes app

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, viewcontroller

I have a 2vcs. Main vc is *ViewController and the other *Questions. The start button works fine in taking me to Questions.vc but the app crashes when I try to go back to ViewController.vc from Questions.vc. The Quit button is declared in Questions.H and the button is linked up, but the app crashes once I b&r and hit the quit button.

After turning on all Exception breakpoints. It shows 10 breakpoints with 3 disabled. These are the lines of code:
Questions.H all three of these lines

`

```
-(IBAction)OphthalmicInstruments:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)Lenses:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)Transposition:(id)sender;
```

`

Questions.M (the blue arrow points to the space b/t these two lines
`

```
-(IBAction)OphthalmicInstruments:(id)sender{

    Cat1.hidden = YES;
```

`
Questions.M Lines with blue arrow Case 2 Answer 3 & Case 3 Wrong 4

`

```
      case 2:
            Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A tonometer measures:"];
            Right3.hidden = NO;
            Wrong2.hidden = NO;
            Wrong3.hidden = NO;
            Wrong4.hidden = NO;
            Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interpupillary distance"];
            Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex distance"];
            Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intraocular pressure"];
            Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basecurve"];
            break;
        case 3: 
            Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A lens clock measures:"];
            Right4.hidden = NO;
            Wrong2.hidden = NO;
            Wrong3.hidden = NO;
            Wrong4.hidden = NO;
            Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interpupillary distance"];
            Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex distance"];
            Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intraocular pressure"];
            Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basecurve"];
            break;
```

`
Questions.M lines: break & case 8 lines both have blue arrows

`

```
        case 7:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The power of a lens is measured in    
_____."];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Millimeters"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inches"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nanometers"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Diopters"];
        break;
    case 8:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A lens with a power of 1 Diopter has a focal length of _____."];
```

`

Comment: Why have you asked the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297034/ios-error-thread-1-under-auto-release-pool-exc-bad-access

Comment: Thanks to your other question I have realized what you are trying to do. Why would you do that? It is terrible. You already have an instance of `ViewController` and you have just added a subview over the top of it. You need to be removing the instance of `Questions` view from the controller. Why aren't you using a `UINavigationController` that would suit your purpose a lot better as if would sort your back button out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) What does this have to do with `xcode`? Answer : **Nothing** So please don't use that tag.

2) Your app doesn't crash at `return UIApplicationMain(...` it says it does cause your not catching the `error`/`exception`. To find out where it is breaking you need to be adding in a `Catch all exceptions`.

You can do this by going to the `Exceptions` section of the Navigation controller in xcode.

[image: xcode exceptions window]

Once you have navigated here you will notice a `+` at the bottom left of the window. Select this so it brings up another small window with two options

[image: Exception options]

You will need to select `Add Exception Breakpoint`

Once you have selected this you will get a new window

[image: All exceptions]

All you need to do is leave the default settings in and click `Done` unless you want to play with them. This will make it so when the exception is throw it should bring at the line it crashes on or the general area making it easier to identify the issue.

This might not solve your issue but it is a step closer to solving it. When you get the general area of the error please comment and I will update my answer to include how to solve it, if I can.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am not a programmer as you can probably tell, but I am trying to learn. I appreciate you breaking everything down very simply for me. BTW added Xcode 4.2 as a tag b/c I realized I am working with an older version & didn't know if that had something to do with my issues. Anyway..I followed your instructions about turning on Exception Breakpoints and it shows 10Breakpoints total with 3 disabled. Questions.H

Answer (score 2):

I was creating something really similar and ran into the same problem. What I did was changed the code that went back and forth between VCs.

So for mine I changed it to
First is my main page Viewcontroller to Questions in my ViewController.m

-(IBAction)StartQuiz:(id)sender{

```
Questions *MenuToQuestions = [[Questions alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
MenuToQuestions.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:MenuToQuestions animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Now here is what I have in my Questions.m

-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender{

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

}